# Спиральная матрица на NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Таск на *NodeJS*: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кажется я нашел решение, но на C++. Оно выглядит следующим образом

```
int main()
{
int const n=5;
 int A[n][n];
 int i=1,j,k,p=n/2;
 for(k=1;k<=p;k++)
 {
 for (j=k-1;j<n-k+1;j++) A[k-1][j]=i++;
 for (j=k;j<n-k+1;j++) A[j][n-k]=i++;
 for (j=n-k-1;j>=k-1;--j) A[n-k][j]=i++;
 for (j=n-k-1;j>=k;j--) A[j][k-1]=i++;
 }
 if (n%2==1) A[p][p]=n*n;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
   printf(" %4d ",A[i][j]);
   if(j==n-1) printf("\n");
  }   
}
```

Также мне предоставили шаблон для решения этой задачи.

```js
function fillSpiralMatrix(n) {
  const result = [[]];

  // Ваш код

  return result;
}

export default fillSpiralMatrix;
```

*Вопрос* заключается в том что я не до конца понимаю зачем в начале функции объявлять константу, которая по сути должна принимать в себя спиральную матрицу и в конечном итоге должна возвращять .

Или эту константу стоит вовсе удалить и создать новый массив?

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, предполагается, что `result` должен постепенно заполняться в ходе работы функции. Хотя лично мне кажется, что проще сразу создать массив нужного размера.

В порядке извращения/развлечения родился следующий код:

```js
function fillSpiralMatrix(n) {
  let result = Array.from({length : n}, () => Array.from({length : n}, () => 0));

  const dir = (function * () {
    let dx = -1;
    let dy = 1;
    let dir = {x : 1, y : 0};
    while (true) {
      yield dir;
      dir.x += dx;
      dir.y += dy;
      dx = dir.x ? -dx : dx;
      dy = dir.y ? -dy : dy;
    }
  })();

  let num = 1;
  let i = 0, j = 0;
  let delta = dir.next().value;
  while (num <= n*n) {
    result[i][j] = num++;
    let newI = (n + i + delta.y) % n;
    let newJ = (n + j + delta.x) % n;
    if (result[newI][newJ] > 0) delta = dir.next().value;
    i += delta.y;
    j += delta.x;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(fillSpiralMatrix(5)).replace(/\],\[/g, ']\n['));
//export default fillSpiralMatrix;
```

Comment: Cпасибо за новый вариант решения задачи :). Но как выяснилось проблема скорее всего в самом unite тесте которые видимо даже не запускаются